# How to change horizontal alignment of adaptive card inputs?

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

`Input.Text` and other Input types in `Adaptive Cards` doesn't have layout property "`horizontalAlignment`" .. which is very weird ... how can I overcome this limitation and make   (Input.Text) aligned to Right instead of Left ???

Comment: Issue opened in the Adaptive Cards [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3230) on GitHub